# No such file or directory using I/O redirection

Tags: command-line, bash, io

I am using I/O redirection in Linux to take input from a file named `input.txt` and output the results to `output.txt`.

The command:
`/home/gajeet/Documents/OpenSource/Test < input.txt > output.txt`

The error:

```
warning: An error occurred while redirecting file 'input.txt'
open: No such file or directory
```

**Note**: Boths files `input.txt` and `output.txt` are in the same directory hierarchy inside the folder `/OpenSource`.

Comment: Are you currently inside that directory when running this command?

Comment: No I am in my home directory

Comment: And is there an `input.txt` in your home directory?

Comment: My input.txt directory is home/gajeet/Documents/OpenSource/input.txt

Comment: Then use that path for the redirection.

Comment: Oh okay I get it

Comment: Thanks a lot @muru